# App store submission bundle invalid

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I'm encountering a mystery issue while trying to upload an iOS app to the app store. Here is the issue:
[image]

I'm using the XCode 5.1 and the target deployment of the app is 7.0

I've tried too many things but it didn't work. Does anyone have any workaround for this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update Xcode to 5.1.1. Since yesterday (5/15) Apple requires new apps to be built using 5.1.1. [See here.](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=04252014a)

Comment: I will try it and we'll see

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
You need install new Xcode with version 5.1.1.
It will resolve the issue.

Comment: I will try it and we'll see